# Sipgate how to handle incoming VOIP calls Python

Tags: python, sip, voip

I Have been wondering , how can we handle incoming calls with sipgate https://api.sipgate.com/v2 API using python. I am able to initiate calls but I've no idea how to handle incoming calls , i can't even find anything on api doc.

After doing some research I came to know that , we can handle incoming calls via sipgate.io. If anyone have any previous experience with it , please help me to get start with incoming calls.

This is what i'm looking for in my app :

1. Handle incoming calls
2. Handle dtmf(when a user makes an entry of digits during a call like options 1-9)
3. on the basis of selection , Python script needs to perform some actions

Answer (score 0):

To get DTMF data, you need to use the [Push-API](https://www.sipgate.io/push-api/api-references) from sipgate.io.
Your server needs to supply a URL, which can then be setup in the [sipgate web interface](https://developer.sipgate.io/push-api/setup/).
Every time you get an incoming call, you will get an incoming Webhook (HTTP) request, which supplies you with [information about the call](https://developer.sipgate.io/push-api/api-reference/#new-call), like its call-id.

The call-id can then be used [in the REST-API](https://developer.sipgate.io/rest-api/authentication/).

After receiving the Webhook, send a `Gather`-Follow Up [XML-response](https://developer.sipgate.io/push-api/api-reference/#gather) to get DTMF data.
Here is the example Response you can send to play a sound file and receive follow up events for DTMF data:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather onData="http://localhost:3000/dtmf" maxDigits="3" timeout="10000">
        <Play>
            <Url>https://example.com/example.wav</Url>
        </Play>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Afterwards [you will receive `onData`-events](https://developer.sipgate.io/push-api/api-reference/#ondata).

---

In case node.js is an option for you, you could consider using the sipgate.io node-library.
There also exists [an example for your use-case](https://github.com/sipgate-io/sipgateio-node-examples/blob/main/webhook/webhook_gather.ts) utilising the library.

To use the Push API, you have to book the sipgate.io package, that includes 100 free API Calls per Month.